# $RANDOM in $PS1 is not updated

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, terminal

I am currently trying to create a custom bash prompt, but `$RANDOM` is not behaving as i would expect, and I hope someone in here can explain why it is behaving as it does.

I currently have a very simple bash script, lets call it `test.sh`

```
function __showPrompt() {
  echo "
  date: $(date)
  random 1: $RANDOM
  random 2: $RANDOM
  "
}

PS1="\$(__showPrompt)"
```

Now when I run `source test.sh` my prompt becomes the output of the date and two random numbers as i would expect.

```
date: Thu Aug  2 15:13:13 CEST 2018
random 1: 24379
random 2: 17139
```

But after that, when I run a command and the prompt is re-run i get and updated time stamp but the `$RANDOM`-value remains the same

```
date: Thu Aug  2 15:19:32 CEST 2018
random 1: 24379
random 2: 17139
```

If I manually run `__showPrompt` the values are updated

```
date: Thu Aug  2 15:20:23 CEST 2018
random 1: 30953
random 2: 6153
```

And what makes this even weirder is that my prompt updates to the same values. The same is true if i run `echo $RANDOM` in the terminal, which again causes my prompts random values to change (and then be stuck).

```
date: Thu Aug  2 15:23:02 CEST 2018
random 1: 30953
random 2: 6153


date: Thu Aug  2 15:23:02 CEST 2018
random 1: 30953
random 2: 6153

echo $RANDOM
30953

date: Thu Aug  2 15:23:08 CEST 2018
random 1: 6153
random 2: 32728


date: Thu Aug  2 15:23:10 CEST 2018
random 1: 6153
random 2: 32728
```

I am not sure what is going on, but it appears to me as `$RANDOM` only is seeded if run in an actual terminal and never inside `$PS1`.

Hope anyone with more bash knowledge than me can explain what is going on

Remark: I am on a MacOS, but I don't see that it should make much of a difference here.

Comment: Bash 4.3.48(1)-release on Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS – your original code works, numbers do change.

Comment: The numbers also change for me in bash v3.2.57 under macOS 10.13.6. But not for the obvious reason; `$( )` runs its contents in a subshell, so using $RANDOM in that doesn't update the main shell's random number generator state. It'd probably be better to use the [`PROMPT_COMMAND` variable](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x264.html) for this.